# Storage of Json data to mysql database using php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, leap-motion

I am doing a leapmotion webapp on PHP and javascript.it is based on gesture recognition. The values of the leapmotion must be stored into the database and when the corresponding gesture is matched the description of the gesture must be displayed. The values from the leapmotion is converted to JSON format. How can I store the JSON data to the mysql database 5.0.?
The JSON file content is:

> `{"name":"HA","pose":true,"data":[[{"x":0.16616291409773337,"y":-0.061424365133667,"z":-0.014198921561969446,"stroke":1},{"x":0.058005894163526694,"y":-0.05005164610312531,"z":0.029463953896938344,"stroke":1},{"x":-0.05015112577067998,"y":-0.03867892707258362,"z":0.07312682935584591,"stroke":1},{"x":-0.1583081457048866,"y":-0.02730620804204193,"z":0.1167897048147537,"stroke":1},{"x":-0.2664651656390933,"y":-0.01593348901150024,"z":0.16045258027366138,"stroke":1},{"x":-0.3746221855732999,"y":-0.00456076998095855,"z":0.20411545573256906,"stroke":1},{"x":0.6253778144267002,"y":0.19795540534387668,"z":-0.5697496025117985,"stroke":1}]]}`

The error which i get is Syntax error. The work is based on Rob O'leary's leaptrainer.js which can be found on https://github.com/roboleary/LeapTrainer.js/tree/master.

Comment: please provide your erroneus php code.

Comment: $sql = "insert into script(lid,message) values(1,'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["data"])."')";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

Comment: i sent the data field of json data to php from javascript and in php i had tried to save it to the database but a syntax error occured

Comment: I can't find a syntax error in your provided code, but you should use `mysqli_real_escape_string` (with an i). Anyway if you have a php syntax error it must be somewhere else.

Comment: sir, syntax error is gone,only lid values are being inserted but under message the values are not being inserted.

Comment: hello did you found a solution to store these data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation I'd prefer to do next:

1. Create separate table for these data. Keys are dependable from your
   purposes, but as quick solution just create table with the same
   columns names as in your JSON.
2. Create some model, to communicate with DB. Make there some
   methods(like saveMotion, getMotion etc.)
3. In your php code, use `json_decode` function, to convert JSON to std
   object. Not sure here if you will be able to write std class to db,
   but conversion it to array would give you a 100% possibility to do
   that.